# DataTable not accepting json from database

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, database

I want to set up a datatable on my website and I found a table I want to use [here](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple) and I have been trying to convert it over to what I need. I have not had much success in this endeavor. My current situation is the table is not populating with rows from a database table and I am getting a json response error. I can open the inspector look at the php file that queries the database returns json data and I can see that I am returning data in the format

```
    {"data":[
{"ssn":"100192686","dob":"1977-02-01","fn":"Latoyia","mi":"H","ln":"Herdon"},
{"ssn":"100263201","dob":"1962-06-15","fn":"Adena","mi":"M","ln":"Couch"}
]}
```

which according to a json validator is valid json but when I reload my page I get an error

```
 "table id=example - Invalid JSON response".
```

So if the json data is in the correct format but is not being returned correctly what do I do? here is a [gihub](https://github.com/Davidson2727/pop) for the project. I have included the mysql database file I am working with as well as a text file that has XHR results in it. I feel like this line  $('#example').DataTable( { javascript is where my issue is

```
<?php
    include_once 'header.php';
?>
<script src = 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js'></script>
<script src = 'https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js'></script>
<script src = 'https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js'></script>
<script src = 'https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/js/dataTables.select.min.js'></script>
<script src = 'JS/dataTables.editor.min.js'></script>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.5/css/select.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "https://editor.datatables.net/extensions/Editor/css/editor.dataTables.min.css">
<section class="main-container">
    <div class="main-wrapper">
        <h2>Home</h2>
        <?php
            if (isset($_SESSION['u_id'])) {
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee;";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                if($resultCheck > 0){
                    echo
                    "<table id='example' class='display' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th></th>
                                    <th>ssn</th>
                                    <th>dob</th>
                                    <th>first</th>
                                                    <th>MI</th>
                                                    <th>last</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>";
                }
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</section>

<script>

console.log("In the script open");


var editor; // use a global for the submit and return data rendering in the examples

$(document).ready(function() {


        editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "infograb.php",
            table: "#example",
            fields: [ {
                    label: "Social#:",
                    name: "ssn"},
                                    {
                    label: "DOB:",
                    name: "dob"},
                                    {label: "First Name:",
                    name: "fn"},
                                    {
                    label: "Middle Initial:",
                    name: "mi"},
                                    {
                    label: "Last Name:",
                    name: "ln"
                        }
            ]
    } );


    $('#example').on( 'click', 'tbody td', function (e) {
        var index = $(this).index();

        if ( index === 1 ) {
            editor.bubble( this, ['fn', 'mi', 'ln'], {
                title: 'Edit name:'
            } );
        }
        else if ( index === 2 ) {
            editor.bubble( this, {
                buttons: false
            } );
        }
        else if ( index === 3 ) {
            editor.bubble( this );
        }

    } );

        var testData = [{
                  "ssn": "98727748",
                  "dob": "2016-02-05",
                  "fn": "jake",
                                    "mi": "a",
                                    "ln": "butler"
                }];

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: "Bfrtip",
        ajax:{
                    url: 'infograb.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                    json: JSON.stringify({ "data": testData })
                    },
                    dataSrc: 'data'
                        },
        columns: [
                        {//sets the checkbox
                            data: null,
                            defaultContent: '',
                            className: 'select-checkbox',
                            orderable: false
                         },
                        { data: "dob" },
            { data: "ssn" },
                        { data: "fn" },
                        { data: "mi" },
                        { data: "ln" },


        ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ],
        select: {
            style:    'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child'
        },
        buttons: [
            { extend: "create", editor: editor },
            { extend: "edit",   editor: editor },
            { extend: "remove", editor: editor }
        ]
    } );
} );





console.log("End script");


</script>

<?php
    include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

and here is the php file that queries the database and returns(allegedly) the json data

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconn.php';


 $rows = array();

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
 $result = $conn->query($sql) or die("cannot write");
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $rows[] = $row;
 }

 echo "<pre>";
 print json_encode(array('data'=>$rows));
 echo "</pre>";

 ?>
```

I have been at this for about 24 hours now, and I feel like I have a bonehead mistake here I just can't figure it out. Any help would talk me down off the cliff at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables can be a pain and it's worthwhile to make sure you read the documents provided by them as much as you can.

I can see 2 issues running over your code without running tests. First one is infograb.php won't save any data sent to it because all it does is return data when it's loaded. Secondly you are using the initiation code of the datatable to try and send data (presumably for the inline editing as you don't seem to require any variables to be sent for the data requested). My first step would be taking it back a step:

```
ajax:{
       url: 'infograb.php',
       type: 'POST',
       data: {
           json: JSON.stringify({ "data": testData })
        },
        dataSrc: 'data'
     },
```

Should go back to

```
ajax:{
       url: 'infograb.php',
     },
```

Remove the pre tags from infograb.php as well as they are unnecessary.

That should load the data into the table for you. You can then start working on the editing side.

Worthwhile Reading and Documentation:

[Ajax sourced data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html)

[PHP libraries](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/)

[DataTables Editor 1.7.3 - PHP 5.3+ libraries](https://editor.datatables.net/docs/1.7.3/php/)

Comment: pre tags actually helped when I stated, for some reason I was only getting the last row in the table and pre tags solved it. But with the changes you suggested it is now unnecessary. I am populating the table now, but clicking causes an row identifier error     dataTables.editor.min.js:10 Uncaught Unable to find row identifier For more information, please refer to https://datatables.net/tn/14 But based on what you said in your answer I think that's expected and I'm looking of a solution now. Thanks for the help man.

Comment: no problem, I had a lot of issues with datatables, they are great when you can get the hang of them. 

Assuming ssn will be unique for each row (given the nature of the ssn) you can update this on the editor section
 editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "infograb.php",
            table: "#example",
            idSrc:  'ssn',
Alternatively you can add a database identifier such as auto increment ID to the json and use that to make updating the database more specific but decision is up to you.

Comment: I followed the error link and found idSrc: 'what to use for id' and I'm using that (you were right about the power of documentation!) now I'm dealing with the edit and delete buttons not working, and add doesn't add new employees but it will readd the original 2500 employees again. I'll mark this question as solved and ask another if I can't figure out my button issues, Thanks again for all the help and useful resources!

Comment: Its adding the whole list again because you are asking it to.
 editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            ajax: "infograb.php",

and then in "infograb.php" you are not receiving any of the $_POST fields.